# Place a widget side by side rather than on top of each other

Tags: plugins

I am using the GD Star plugin to monitor what people are rating the apps located on my site, http://tablified.com. I want to place the widgets (the ones that tell me which of the apps are top rated) side by side but unfortunately I can only place the widgets on top of each other. Is there any way I can force them to be side by side. Having the widgets stacked doesn't utilize the space and it just makes the page extremely long and look ugly. I am sure that this can be done with any widget but GD Star is what I am using. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The markup for widgets depends on sidebar they are placed in and controlled by [`wp_register_sidebar()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar) arguments, used for it.

The actual presentation of them in front end depends on how theme styles that markup. This is mostly CSS issue and has little to do with WordPress.

Comment: I apologize. I didn't mean to post in the wrong section. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

Come On . Do you need a tutorial in HTML now.You can control div layout by CSS
Here is the code :-

```
<div class="sidebars">
<div class="sidebar">
<?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-one'); ?>
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
<?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-two'); ?>
</div>
......
</div>
```

CSS :-

```
.sidebar{
width:22%;
float:left;
padding:1%;
}
```

I hope you can complete the rest now.You will need to register sidebars before calling them. :)